# In Doctor Who “Arachnids in the UK” what happened to the spider in the Apartment?

Tags: doctor-who

What happened to the spider that was left in the apartment in the building where Yasmin's family lives in? The Doctor told the spider to stay and then close the apartment door and that was the last we see of this situation.

Comment: We also don't see what happens to the other spiders. It's just implied that they found a solution.

Comment: They lured them all to the hotel, didn't they? I assumed it include the one found in the apartment building.

Comment: @MrLister - I'm sure that previous Dr Who episodes they provided a quick glimpse of the final outcome, but why not show a quick reference to the Spider solution instead of implying a solution was created... I just like closed endings to make the episode complete... but maybe they will return to the spider epidemic in another episode?

Comment: @tilley31 - I understand that they use the speakers in the panic room to lure the spiders but how did it travel all the way to the apartment? It would've need to be some awesome speakers and bass to travel all the way to the apartment... I don't think that they even pointed the speakers to the ground to get maximum vibrations.

Answer (score 2):

As in almost all of the episodes in this season so far, the "enemy" turns out to be an innocent victim of the real enemy, mankind. In the end, the spiders were just brought "home" and trapped, and we saw that their exponential growth (which would continue through their lifespan) would eventually kill them anyway.

The spider that was left in the flat would therefore either:

- have returned home and been trapped when the mother called them; or
- have died due to its abnormal growth before it was able to.

Answer (score 0):

At the middle of the episode, we can see that spiders where very numerous around the hotel area. There is also a dead spider in Graham's house which died of starvation.

We should assume that now that the threat is known (just Earth mutated spiders who escaped), the scientific lab will just have to search for the remaining spiders found on the map, even the one in the appartment, before they grow the size of a car...

Comment: Assuming things to complete the episode is just too harsh for the audience, they could've had a quick shot of exterminators walking around to provide some closure. If the audience has to assume things then what is the point of watching Dr Who... In Dr Who, she/he gets into trouble and saves everyone... and hence no need to turn on the TV... kinda boring.